# Clearing input field when using Vue with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I would like to clear inputs after I add a new todo in my vuex todo app, and I am wondering if this is application state, and should be handled with vuex, or component state, which should be handled within the component itself. Right now I just have a `v-model` attached to the input which holds onto an empty string:

`<input v-model="text"...>`

Inside my component:

`data(){
    return{
       text: ''
     }
  }`

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/YWBAqP

Answer (score 0):

I follow a rule of thumb to determine when something needs to be an application level state and when something needs to be at component level.

Any state that just affects the local view of a component and will never be required outside the view can be a local state. If you have opted for `vuex` ideally you will avoid this also.

Everything else should go to the application level state. Then clearning the input after adding something is just a matter of setting `this.text=""` in the `addTodo` method.